# How does matplotlib determine its x limits?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to find out on what basis matplotlib sets its automatic plot limit.

The question arose when I plotted some `x_values` against some `y_values`.
For the `x_values` the following holds: `min(x_values) = -801.01` and `max(x_values) = 798.80`. The limits set by matplotlib are `(-1000, 800)`.

As the data is almost symmetrical around 0, therefore I would like it to be plotted symmetrically around 0. Is there anyway I can tell matplotlib to automatically center the plot? Also matplotlib seems to set the "resolution" on it's limits as 200 in this case which seems a bit high to me.

Of course I could set limits manually, but I want to avoid that if possible.

PS: I don't know if it matters but I plot the values somewhere and later add the `Line2D` object to the figure.

Comment: What do you mean with _avoid setting limits manually_? Matplotlib can't guess that you want an axis symmetric around zero, so it will always involve some command. You could keep things short with e.g. `pl.xlim(-np.abs(pl.xlim()).max(), np.abs(pl.xlim()).max())`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Matplotlib obviously does guess the limits. and maybe there is some way to tweak its settings a little. Also the plotting and the data handling is  done in different classes in my program. While I technicallly could access the data in the drawing class, I prefer not to.